# Photoshop CS6 - Remove glare/hue from image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]How can I remove the glare/hue from either side of this image?

Heres what's been tried to remove the glare/hue.

- Auto Tone
- Reducing the colour balance blue tone for shadows (Makes the whole image yellow)
- Reducing the Gamma correction (-)
- Using curves to reduce the blue channel over the blue hued area. (Makes the whole image yellow)

Comment: What have you tried? Why is it failing?

Comment: Will I tried auto tone, adjusting the exposure and gamma correction, increasing the blue tone in colour balance, doesn't take away the blueish hue on either side of the image.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question clearly shows your *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; ***show*** *us* what you tried and failed!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a curves adjustment layer, but use a gradient as a mask, so that the curves can be applied selectively only to the areas that need it. Here I adjusted the blue channel curve, and also the RGB curve.

The result shown below is not perfect and could be tweaked if you have more time. Since the edit is non-destructive, you can alter the curves, or even the opacity of the adjustment layer until you're happy with the result.

But anyway here's the example:

[image]

Edit: In the example below, here I've done a bit more work with more adjustment layers, plus I got rid of the horrible edges using the content aware fill. I notice I can now see the colours of the tapestry/screen in the background, and it seems to have removed the yellow tinge of the faces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This sort of did the trick, however how did you get the gradient mask in the gif above?

Comment: @user2240778 I used the gradient tool to make a gradient on a new layer, and then Ctrl+click in one of the channels in the Channels palette to load it as a selection. Back to the layers, and delete the gradient layer, then add a curves adjustment, and the mask is automatically added

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is using Burn tool.

Select **Burn** tool (Press O. There are 3 tools. Default is Dodge. You can expand it to select the Burn tool).

In the menu bar, select Midtones. Increase the size of tool (diameter can be around the area you want to fix) by pressing **]** key.

Move the tool on both sides of the image vertically. And you'll see the following result:

[image]